# html5 video buffering failed part way

Tags: html, video, video.js, buffering, seek

Using Visual Studio as my local server while I'm trying to learn to manage html5 video with video.js. My thing is I can get video playing very easily, but I can't seek or pause without breaking the video. If I click play and just let it play all the way through it plays with no issue.

Error I get is:

> Network error has a caused the video download to fail part way.:

I am wondering if it has to do with the default HTTP server visual studio uses and if so is their a guide to managing this on the server side? Looked around but not 100% sure where to start. New to web programming, but been programming native stuff for awhile.

Edit:

So the problem is entirely with the Visual Studio debugging server. Just using a directory with a browser is good enough, but was wanting a bit more options so built a basic node.js server from the tutorial here. http://blog.dojchinovski.mk/?p=41

Answer (score 0):

Look at my edit in the top post for the answer.